# Get all Top N rank records in java

Tags: java

i have a HashMap resultdata like below

```
"zip000", 1234
"zip001", 2345
"zip002", 3456
"zip003", 4567
"zip004", 7890
"zip005", 7890
"zip006", 123
"zip007", 234
"zip010", 7890
"zip011", 678
"zip012", 789
"zip013", 890
```

and used below code

```
  public static List<String> topNKeys(final HashMap<String, Integer> map, int n) {
    PriorityQueue<String> topN = new PriorityQueue<String>(n, new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return Integer.compare(map.get(s1), map.get(s2));
        }
    });

    for(String key:map.keySet()){
        if (topN.size() < n)
            topN.add(key);
        else if (map.get(topN.peek()) < map.get(key)) {
            topN.poll();
            topN.add(key);
        }
    }
    return (List) Arrays.asList(topN.toArray());
}
```

Above code displays me topN records as

Assume n= 6

```
zip001=2345
zip002=3456
zip003=4567
zip005=7890
zip010=7890
zip004=7890
```

But i need it to give all top 6 resultdata according to Integer Rank, i mean like below

```
zip013=890
zip000=1234
zip001=2345
zip002=3456
zip003=4567
zip005=7890
zip010=7890
zip004=7890
```

According to integers where 7890,4567,3456,2345,1234,890 are the top 5 Integers.

How could i do this? Any kind of help and suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by **according to Integer Rank**? What is this rank?

Comment: Remember the previous value. Increase `n` by one  if `key` is equal to the previous value.

Comment: @Nico Van Belle Here according to Integer Rank, i mean, Integer with same value will be given single rank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in two steps:

1. gather the distinct top N numbers
2. collect all the entries that have a value in the top N

In terms of code, you could write it like this:

```
public static List<Entry<String, Integer>> topNKeys(Map<String, Integer> map, int n) {
  Set<Integer> topValues = getTopValues(map, n);
  return getEntriesWithTopValues(map, topValues);
}

//Returns the distinct top n values
private static Set<Integer> getTopValues(Map<String, Integer> map, int n) {
  TreeSet<Integer> values = new TreeSet<>(map.values());
  Set<Integer> topNValues = new HashSet<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Integer v = values.pollLast();
    if (v != null) topNValues.add(v);
    else break;
  }
  return topNValues;
}

//Returns the entries with a value that is contained in topValues
private static List<Entry<String, Integer>> getEntriesWithTopValues(Map<String, Integer> map, Set<Integer> topValues) {
  return map.entrySet().stream()
          .filter(e -> topValues.contains(e.getValue()))
          .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue())
          .collect(toList());
}
```

Applied to your example, it returns the desired output.

Without stream, the last method could be written:

```
private static List<Entry<String, Integer>> getEntriesWithTopValues(Map<String, Integer> map, Set<Integer> topValues) {
  List<Entry<String, Integer>> result = new ArrayList<> ();
  for (Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
    if (topValues.contains(e.getValue())) result.add(e);
  }

  Collections.sort(result, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> e1, Entry<String, Integer> e2) {
      return e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. OP needs the limit to be not a fixed amount, but a fixed count of distinct values. So the result may be more than the limit, with a couple of duplicates.

Comment: @assylias I am using java 7, so stream is not usable. Can you please java 7 compatible code

Comment: @daisy I have added a version without streams.

Comment: @assylias  I am trying to sort result in desc order, so i am using this code  Collections.sort(topNKeys(map,  n), Collections.reverseOrder()); and Collections.sort(topNKeys(map,  6)); .But using this i am not able to sort. and tried with    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>()
        {} but this gives me more and more error.

Comment: @daisy I've added the sorting step.